# Sieve of Eratosthenes in python with threading

Tags: python, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Is it possible to program a Sieve of Eratosthenes in Python with threading to enable faster output? Ive seen a lot of Sieve of Eratosthenes written in python but never one that has threading. Is it impossible because of the GIL?

Comment: You should try it, and test it. Threads typically improve performance of I/O bound processes.

Comment: Threads will not improve cpu-bound processes, and it's not trivial to multiprocess the calculation because there will be a lot of IPC. https://stackoverflow.com/q/16887793/4799172

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sieve is going to process a number of primes that is large enough to require offloading bitmaps to disk, it may become relevant to use threads. Due to the nature of the sieve, you have to expect a lot of contention between the threads because they will all want to update the same files (at least initially).

Lets say you use bits to represent the positions of flagged numbers in the sieve and you break it down in 8K files (65536 bits), the first primes you find will have something to update in every single file so the benefits of parallelism will be lost to file access conflicts.  Once you reach primes that are larger than 65536, there will be a lot fewer conflits and the threads will start to bring some benefits.

You will still have to find a way to prevent the controlling process (that finds the next eligible number and launches the threads) from moving ahead of the threads' update process.

A better strategy could be to make the chunk size equal to the product of the first few primes.  This would allow the initial creation of the files to use an identical bitmap repeated over and over and would also reduce the file access conflicts at the beginning of the process.

For example,  if the chunk size is 2*3*5*7 (210) your files would hold 210 bits with a repeatable pattern that covers flagging of these 4 factors. i.e. bits for 1..210 are the same as those for 211..420, 421..630, and so on.   You would, of course use a larger number of factors to have meaningful file sizes.